# Maximum number of students can be seated in a class

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-optimization

> > Due to  Coronavirus health procedures,
> >     students inside classroom have to be distanced $2$ meter from each other,
> >     If the classroom dimensions are $(M \times N)$ , **What is the maximum** number of students can be seated in the classroom?

Is there a general rule for this question?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square).  These problems are notoriously difficult, and there is no efficient solution method in general.
For example, according to the web site [The best known packings of equal circles in a square](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/csq/) we might not know (rigorously, at least) the smallest square room that could hold $31$ students.

... unless you want to assume the students are arranged in a rectangular array.

Comment: You might also want to have a teacher in the classroom, and also worry about whether the students will be able to get in and out of the door.